# How to select MS SQL Server database in GUI (WPF)?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, database, user-interface

I'm developing WPF application and want to have an opportunity to change DB via user interface. I use only MS SQL Server and don't want to select Odbc data sources for that purpose. Neither I want to edit connection string manually - I think it's too difficult for an ordinary user.

What's the best practice for that issue?

Comment: So what are you asking? Do you want the program to generate the connection strings?

Answer (score 0):

Add all the connectionstrings you want to have in your gui. And query all the connectionstrings in your viewmodel

```
foreach(var con in ConfigurationManager.Connectionstrings)
{
    Connections.Add(con.Name);
}
```

Something like this.